# Instantiate model with columns

Tags: phalcon

How can I instantiate a model and get all columns already declared in the instance?

```
$modelA = User::findFirst();
echo $modelA->id; //OK
$modelB = new User();
echo $modelA->id; //Id is undeclared causing errors instead of returning blank
```

Currently I need to declare by hand the model columns in the event `onConstruct` but I want to make use of the [database introspection](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#meta-data-strategies) strategy and get properties declared from the table schema schema when I use `new User();`.

Anyone knows something that can help me out?!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Annotations Strategy mentioned on that [page](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#meta-data-strategies).

So, something like

```
class Test extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    /**
     * @Primary
     * @Identity
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    public $id;
...
```

Get an instance of the meta-data adapter from the services container:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Apc as ApcMetaData,
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Strategy\Annotations as StrategyAnnotations;

$di['modelsMetadata'] = function() {

    // Instantiate a meta-data adapter
    $metaData = new ApcMetaData(array(
        "lifetime" => 86400,
        "prefix"   => "my-prefix"
    ));
```

Get the columns for your model like so:

```
<?php

$test = new Test();

// Get Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata instance
$metaData = $test->getModelsMetaData();

// Get fields names
$attributes = $metaData->getAttributes($test);
print_r($attributes);

// Get fields data types
$dataTypes = $metaData->getDataTypes($test);
print_r($dataTypes);
```

All of the above can be found in the link.

Also check out the [MetaData APIs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_MetaData.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you mate! But, as I said, I need to still making use of the introspection strategy.